# LINQ to SQL - Get a string from a Var

Tags: c#, sql, linq, string

I'm new to LINQ to SQL world - So I'm sorry if the question is stupid :) - I just could not find any answer on the internet:

I have a table with two columns - "Batch_Name" and "Batch_id".
The user select the batch id and the application needs to return its name.

I have this C# Code to extract the batch name according to the batch id ("myBatchNum"):

```
        var thisBatch = from x in gridDB.batches
                        where x.batch_id == myBatchNum
                        select new { x.batch_name };


        lblBatchName.Text = thisBatch.First().ToString();
```

This extract from the proper batch name, but when I try to display the name on a label control, I get this result ("NightBatch is the name in the DB):

{batch_name = NightBatch }

How do I extract the batch name from "thisBatch" properly to the label control?

Thank you so much,
Nim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unclear that you need to use an anonymous type at all. Just use:

```
var thisBatch = from x in gridDB.batches
                where x.batch_id == myBatchNum
                select x.batch_name;

lblBatchName.Text = thisBatch.First();
```

Or if you *did* want to use an anonymous type still, just use the property you've effectively created:

```
var thisBatch = from x in gridDB.batches
                where x.batch_id == myBatchNum
                select new { x.batch_name };

lblBatchName.Text = thisBatch.First().batch_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `ToString()` at the end as you already select only the name

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an anonymous type with one property called batch_name.  Chage your code as below to return strings:

```
var thisBatch = from x in gridDB.batches
                where x.batch_id == myBatchNum
                select x.batch_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `ToString()` on the anonymous type you've generated in the `select` statement. Try this:

```
lblBatchName.Text = thisBatch.First().batch_name;
```